# Extended events query in User Database

Tags: extended-events, sql-server-2022

I've been looking at query store results for a user database for a membership system. Performance has been poor with a number of queries timing out and showing inconsistent behavior.

This is a brand new server (Win 2022/ SQL 2022), and the application has exclusive use of the server.

2 of the 3 most resource intensive query (by duration) is one related to [Extended Events for 'system health'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/use-the-system-health-session?view=sql-server-ver16). The EE queries run once per day. Over the last month, the best performance was 28 seconds, degrading to 120 seconds (yet still completing). On 6 days the queries ran longer before failing, ranging from 130 sec to 200.

I know this may seem trivial. I'm focusing on these queries as they stand out as worst performers, and I see no good reason for a stock query to take so long or to fail as it has been.

I also don't understand why something that appears to be a stock system related maintenance query is appearing in the user database query store.

```
select
  cast(XeFileTarget.event_data as xml) as [EventData]
into
  #SystemHealthEventData
from
  sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'system_health*.xel', null, null, null) as XeFileTarget
```

[Actual Execution plan 1](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByJ92c-Qa)

Followed by

```
  select
  XeDeadlockXmlReport.[Name],
  XeDeadlockXmlReport.[Timestamp],
  XeDeadlockXmlReport.DeadlockXmlReport
from
(
  select
    XeEventData.event_data.value('(@name)[1]', 'varchar(19)') as [Name],
    XeEventData.event_data.value('(@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2') as [Timestamp],
    XeEventData.event_data.value('(data[@name="xml_report"]/value/deadlock)[1]/process-list[1]/process[1]/@currentdb', 'int') as DatabaseId,
    cast(XeEventData.event_data.query('(data[@name="xml_report"]/value/deadlock)[1]') as xml) as DeadlockXmlReport
  FROM
    #SystemHealthEventData
    cross apply[EventData].nodes('//event') as XeEventData (event_data)
  where
    XeEventData.event_data.value('(@name)[1]', 'varchar(19)') = 'xml_deadlock_report'
) as XeDeadlockXmlReport
where XeDeadlockXmlReport.DatabaseId = db_id()
```

[Actual execution plan 2](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJYWR5W7p)

Oddly I just ran it, it ran successfully but returned nothing.

As far as I can tell the application vendor hasn't altered or deployed anything. So why would default system  process be so inconsistent and unreliable, and why would a system related extended events trace query appear in the query store for an application specific user database?

Edit. I've run Brent Ozar's Sp_blitz scripts and nothing seems to stand out.

Comment: @J.D.  The extended events queries are failing. Application queries are also failing but less often. As the extended events queries are consuming the most resource i'm starting there, but curious if they're related

Comment: @J.D. Actual plans added. 1st query runs. 1:40. 2nd query runs. 34 sec, returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Today I learned...

The queries are appearing in the user db because that's where they are being run. And although the Extended Events collection is standard, the queries that analyze the data are not. It seems the queries have been implemented by the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file` can put a lot of load on the server since it has to parse out every matching *.xel file and convert that data into XML, all in memory. Therefore, it's generally not a good idea to run this function on your production database if it is at all performance sensitive. It's convenient, but that convenience comes with quite a bit of overhead.

A couple of options for reading this file with lower overhead would first be to just use SSMS directly, either under the running session in Object Explorer or by opening the file directly in SSMS, the later of which can be done on a completely different machine than where you run SQL. Another option is to use QueryableXEventData[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.xevent.linq.queryablexeventdata.-ctor?view=sqlserver-2016#microsoft-sqlserver-xevent-linq-queryablexeventdata-ctor(system-string-system-string-microsoft-sqlserver-xevent-linq-eventstreamsourceoptions-microsoft-sqlserver-xevent-linq-eventstreamcacheoptions)) by specifying a connection string, the session name, and **EventFile for the sourceOption**. That ends up being much more efficient since that particular version of QueryableXEventData uses `sys.fn_MSxe_read_event_stream` which does not do any conversion to XML on the server at all and mostly just sends the raw data of the XEL file to wherever you're running your .NET app with QueryableXEventData.

Comment: Hi Dyllon Thanks for your reply, That's great context.